# Android: passing object from activy to view

Tags: android, view, android-activity

My activity load data from res.raw

To give those datas to the view, I've added a param to the view construtor

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.loadLibrary("engine-2d");

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

    if (_engine == null)
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();       

        byte[] scene;
        int scene_size = 0;
        try {
            InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.package_test);
            scene_size = ins.available(); 
            scene = new byte[scene_size]; 
            ins.read(scene); 
            ins.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Should never happen!
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        _engine = new PlsEngine2D(scene, scene_size, width, height);
    }

    setContentView(new PlsSurface2D(this, _engine));
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    _engine.DestroyEngine();
}
```

I don't know why but when I press the home button (the instance of my program is still in memory)
and then I launch the application again, it crash.

In fact, PlsEngine2D use ndk to call C function that make malloc.

I do not exactly know where is the problem but I wonder if the malloc pointer are still correct !

Or may be this is my view!
I give the _engine object to it.
I wonder if when the view wake up it have the _engine param object again !

Is there another way to give my _engine object to the view ?
Does the view can take the the _engine value to the activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post some code in your question please? I am not sure I am getting the whole picture.

Anyway, when you start an activity that is still in memory, the activity's following methods are called in the following order: onRestart(), onStart() and onResume().

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is called when the activity is still in the memory. It is not created again, since in `onResume()` you dont call `setContentView()` again.

Comment: One important point to add about this - `onResume()` is called directly after `onCreate()`, even if the application isn't in memory.